# Kubuntu 18.04 - Bluetooth Connection Flapping

Tags: kubuntu, bluetooth

I try to use my phone with my Kubuntu 18.04 PC and Bluetooth. I can pair it and the everything works a expected. When I get out of range it gets disconnected. No surprises so far. When I come back the phone does not get reconnected. When I open the KDE Bluetooth setting I see the connection constantly flapping between connected and disconnected. When I open the Bluetooth settings of the phone I see that the PC is not connected. When I tap on it gets connected and everything works as expected again until I get out of range again. I've tested this on an old 16.04 system which does not show this behavior. With the 16.04 PC the Bluetooth connection is reacquired as soon as the phone comes in range.

Other devices (car, headphones, speaker, etc.) reconnect flawlessly and reliable to the phone. I use the same USB Bluetooth adapter on both systems.

I've tried to upgrade to "ppa:bluetooth/bluez". This does not change any thing. This is what I see in syslog while the re connection is in progress:

```
Aug 24 10:07:26 lx-mh-02 bluetoothd[12258]: Unable to get io data for :1.51/Profile/HSPHSProfile/00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Aug 24 10:07:31 lx-mh-02 bluetoothd[12258]: Unable to get Headset Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
Aug 24 10:09:40 lx-mh-02 bluetoothd[12258]: message repeated 11 times: [ Unable to get Headset Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down]
```

And some times I get messages like this:

```
Aug 24 09:27:02 lx-mh-02 kernel: [64421.971216] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 62
```

"lsusb" reports:

```
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

I just want to stay connected. I don't need any audio profile or any thing else as I want to use BlueProximity with Bluetooth and nothing else.

How to fix this on my new 18.04 system?